# How to get this COUNT value to 'small_count' variable

Tags: java, sql, swing, netbeans

I want to know how to get/assign count value for the Jlabel

Code being used:

```
private void small(){
        try{

            String q = "SELECT COUNT(SIZE) FROM uniform WHERE SIZE='S'";
            pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(q);
            rs = (ResultSet) pst.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
                String c = rs.getString("COUNT");
                small_count.setText(c);
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {    
            int showConfirmDialog = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no real point in using a `PreparedStatement` if you are not passing any parameters either inside or out.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't given the returned item a name (it's not `"COUNT"`), so you can't use the string version of `getString`.

The simplest thing would be to give it a name:

```
String q = "SELECT COUNT(SIZE) AS C FROM uniform WHERE SIZE='S'";
// ----------------------------^^^^
```

...and then use that:

```
String c = rs.getString("C");
```

...although since it'll be a number I would use `getInt` or `getLong` instead:

```
int c = rs.getInt("C");
```

But you also have the option of using the [index-based version of `getXyz`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)). Since it's the first thing you're returning, it has index 1:

```
String c = rs.getString(1);
// or
int c = rs.getInt(1);
```

That's just a bit harder to maintain.

Comment: @StefanBeike - LOL, yes, thanks -- I forgot to edit it! :-)

Comment: (And now I've fixed `getInt("COUNT")`, too. Sigh.)

Answer (score 0):

You should only do this "AS COUNT" Add in query. your code will run perfectly.

```
 String q = "SELECT COUNT(SIZE) AS COUNT FROM uniform WHERE SIZE='S'";
```